# How to initialize a google maps on pageinit without repeatingly loading the google map api script

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, dynamically-generated

- I would like to be able to load the Google.maps API only once for alle my pages.
- Then i would like to be able to use geolocation or loading a map into a page anywhere on my web  app.
- The problem is that I cant figure out to seperate API loading and map initialization.
  Which means i need to load the API each time I create a map.

I have referenced most of my code further down in the post but i suppose the following code is the problem.That piece of code takes care of the API Loading but at the same time it takes care of setting the initialize() function as a callback function and calling it.

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src ="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

**How do i load the api once, lets say in the header, and then create a new map each time I go to specific page. WIthout loading the maps API again. (Note that im using Jquery mobile so my header only gets loaded one time for a session.)**

**I get this error:**

Warning: you have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

**Ii would like to tell you my setup.**

-Im using Google Map APi v3

-I'm loading the API dynamically after the page has loaded.

-I'm using Jquery mobile, which means the page with google maps only gets partially reloaded when you     visit it.

-Im using google maps for two things to show the map and for geolocation.

-I'm using the Google map api on several pages.

**Im interacting with the map in 3 different places: In a header javascript see code below**

- A header javascript
- A javascript in the body
- The DIV in the body that holds the map.

Here is my code for the javascript that handles loading the API, showing the map, markers etc:

```
        <script>
            $('.error').hide();
            //search criterias
            var radius;
            var timerange;
            var type;
            //user position variables
            var userposition = false;
            var mylatitudedegree = "=55.698";
            var mylongitudedegree = "=12.579";
            //map variables
            var mapready = false;
            var map;
            var bound;
            var markersArray = [];
            //array for keeping track of the markers
            var markercenter;
            //hack
            var pageinit = 0;
            var initializer = 0;
            var triggersearch = 0;
            var loadscripts = 0;
            var isgooglemapsloaded = false;

                $( '#soegsagside' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event)
                {
                pageinit++;

                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setPosition, function(error) {
                        alert('Din location er ikke tilgængelig! Error code: ' + error.code);
                        userposition = false;
                    }, {
                        maximumAge : 60000,
                        timeout : 10000,
                        enableHighAccuracy : true
                    });
                } 
                else {
                    alert("Din browser tillader ikke, at vise din lokation!");
                    userposition = false;
                }

                loadScript();       

                $("#search_filter_button").click(function() {
                    //hide the "skal udfyldes" labels
                    $('.error').hide();
                    // validate and process form here
                    radius = $("select#choose_radius_select").val();
                    if (radius == "vælg") {
                        $("label#radius_error").show();
                        $("select#choose_radius_select").focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    timerange = $("select#choose_timerange_select").val();
                    if (timerange == "vælg") {
                        $("label#timerange_error").show();
                        $("select#choose_timerange_select").focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    type = $("select#vælg_type").val();
                    if (type == "vælg") {
                        $("label#select_type_error").show();
                        $("select#vælg_type").focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    //------------------post to php script ---------------
                    var dataString = 'radius=' + radius + '&timerange=' + timerange + '&type=' + type + '&mylatitudedegree=' + mylatitudedegree + '&mylongitudedegree=' + mylongitudedegree;
                    $.ajax({
                        type : "POST",
                        url : "soegsagDB.php",
                        data : dataString,
                        success : function(data) {
                            $('#søgeresultater').html(data);
                            $('#søgeresultater').trigger('create');
                            clearOverlays();
                            createtaskmarkers();
                            findCenterOfMarkers();
                            if (userposition) {
                                usergeoposition = new google.maps.LatLng(mylatitudedegree, mylongitudedegree);
                                map.setCenter(usergeoposition);
                                createuserposition(usergeoposition);
                            } else {
                                map.setCenter(markercenter);
                            }
                            expandMapBoundForMarkers()

                        }
                    });
                    //end of post search query to server
                    return false;
                });
                //end of click seach button
            });
            //end of page ready

            function setPosition(position) {
                userposition = true;
                myposition = position.coords;
                mylatitudedegree = position.coords.latitude;
                mylongitudedegree = position.coords.longitude;
                var milli = new Date();
            }

            //function for clearing the markerArray
            function clearOverlays() {
                for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
                    markersArray[i].setMap(null);
                }
            }

            //Function for initializing the map, which is called when the map is created
            function initialize() {
                initializer++;
                bound = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom : 13,
                    center : new google.maps.LatLng(55, 12),
                    mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }

                //Create a map
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
                mapready = true;
                $("#search_filter_button").trigger('click');//Trigger click on the search button
                triggersearch++;
            }

            //create user positio marker
            function createuserposition(usergeoposition) {
                var userPositionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position : usergeoposition,
                    map : map,
                    title : "Din position",
                });
                markersArray.push(userPositionMarker);
            }

            function createtaskmarkers() {
                //Create the markers of the tasks
                //1. find the task <li> that contain the data and loop through each one
                //2. for each task collect the dato into variables and create markers and infowindows
                //3. calculate center of point
                //4. extendt map area to contain all points

                var data = $.map($('li'), function(element) {
                    if (element.hasAttribute("data-latitude")) {

                        var tempPos = new google.maps.LatLng($(element).attr('data-latitude'), $(element).attr('data-longitude'));
                        var link = $(element).attr('data-link');
                        var title = $(element).attr('data-title');
                        var type = $(element).attr('data-type');
                        var date = $(element).attr('data-date');

                        tempMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position : tempPos,
                            map : map,
                            title : title,
                        });

                        tempMarker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png')

                        var tempContentString = '<div style="width: 200px; height: 100px;">' + date + '<br></br>' + '<a href="' + link + '" rel="external"><b>' + type + ' , ' + title + '</b></a>' + '</div>';

                        //Create infowindow
                        var tempInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content : tempContentString
                        });
                        //add market to markerArray
                        markersArray.push(tempMarker);
                        //Create event with infowindow
                        google.maps.event.addListener(tempMarker, 'click', function() {
                            tempInfowindow.open(map, this);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }

            function findCenterOfMarkers() {
                //calculate center of markers and change mapcenter to that
                var sumlatitude = 0;
                var sumlongitude = 0;
                for ( position = 0; position < markersArray.length; position++) {
                    sumlatitude += markersArray[position].getPosition().lat();
                    sumlongitude += markersArray[position].getPosition().lat();
                }
                avglatitude = sumlatitude / markersArray.length;
                avglongitude = sumlongitude / markersArray.length;
                markercenter = new google.maps.LatLng(avglatitude, avglongitude);
            }

            function expandMapBoundForMarkers() {
                //Extend bounds for map to fit all markers into map
                for (var i in markersArray) {
                    bound.extend(markersArray[i].getPosition());
                }
                map.fitBounds(bound);
            }

            //loads the google maps api with KEY and appends the script to the document body
            function loadScript() {
                var script = document.createElement("script");
                script.type = "text/javascript";
                script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC8wZ6RmFySy0DnWvrUaA-2OJqcM1_AOIc&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
                document.body.appendChild(script);
            }
            </script>
```

The only thing in the body of the page that has to do with the maps. Is the DIV that the map is loaded into.

```
<div id="map" style="width: 80%; height: 280px; margin: auto; background-color: gray">Kortet loader, vent venligst.</div> <!--alternative for full screen style="position:absolute;top:30px;bottom:50px;left:0;right:0;"-->
```

The API is also loaded in a common header script. Because I in general need to load it on other pages.

```
<script src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>
```

Comment: I cant seem to find a good answear to this question on the net. I hope you guys can help me. If you want to you can go to my site at www.sammenspil.dk to visit it and study my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready( function () {

        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=mynamespace.init_google_maps";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    $(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    //do stuff here that happens each time a new page is loaded

    });
    });
}); 
</script>
```

the api is loaded once inside .ready(). you can create a new map in the callback that was passed to .bind() which is called each time a new page loads or is inserted. you can initialize the map inside mynamespace. mynamespace is a .js file included on the page